# Problem while Running SMACH program

Tags: ros, rospy, executive-smach, smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying out the tutorials on **SMACH** in ros-indigo.
 I am trying to run this following SMACH program [state_machine_simple.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eacousineau/executive_smach_tutorials/hydro-devel/smach_tutorials/examples/state_machine_simple.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('smach_tutorials')
import rospy
import smach
import smach_ros

# define state Foo
class Foo(smach.State):
    def __init__(self):
        smach.State.__init__(self, outcomes=['outcome1','outcome2'])
        self.counter = 0

    def execute(self, userdata):
        rospy.loginfo('Executing state FOO')
        if self.counter < 3:
            self.counter += 1
            return 'outcome1'
        else:
            return 'outcome2'


# define state Bar
class Bar(smach.State):
    def __init__(self):
        smach.State.__init__(self, outcomes=['outcome2'])

    def execute(self, userdata):
        rospy.loginfo('Executing state BAR')
        return 'outcome2'
        
# main
def main():
    rospy.init_node('smach_example_state_machine')

    # Create a SMACH state machine
    sm = smach.StateMachine(outcomes=['outcome4', 'outcome5'])

    # Open the container
    with sm:
        # Add states to the container
        smach.StateMachine.add('FOO', Foo(), 
                               transitions={'outcome1':'BAR', 
                                            'outcome2':'outcome4'})
        smach.StateMachine.add('BAR', Bar(), 
                               transitions={'outcome2':'FOO'})

    # Execute SMACH plan
    outcome = sm.execute()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But when I  execute it I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "state_machine_simple.py", line 9, in <module>
    class Foo(smach.State):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'State'
```

I don't know how to solve this error... kindly help me out....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226650/problem-while-running-smach-program/) by [Niranjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25953/niranjan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-02-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-02-15**:
In a terminal, type `python` and then try: `from smach import State` Does that result in an error too?

**Comment by [Niranjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25953/niranjan/) on 2016-02-15**:
Hi, I tried that its not showing error.... So I tried including `from smach import State` statement in the program... now its working fine.. thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Adding `from smach import State` statement in the program solves this problem

---

Originally posted by [Niranjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25953/niranjan/) with karma: 51 on 2016-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0